# Return type with try-catch-finally

Tags: java

I have tried the following code snippet:

```
private Integer getnumber() {
    Integer i = null;
    try {
        i = new Integer(5);
        return i;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return 0;
    } finally {
        i = new Integer(7);
    }
}
```

This method returns 5 and not 7.

> Why it returns 5 and not 7?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: very short answer "value of i is already updated in the stack when you say return i" so it is not updated when you update it later

Comment: @Algorithmist This is correct, return value is already in the stack and changing the value later will not affect that. Move it to an answer.

Comment: @user2669894, your question has a well detailed explanation here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864230/javas-return-value-in-try-catch-finally-mechanism, kindly check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `finally` block of a `try..catch..finally` runs after the code within the `try..catch` has completed (be it successfully or not); in the case of your code this is when the `return i` has occured.

Because of this behaviour the value of `i` has already been placed into the return variable of the method before you then assign the new value of 7 to it. The following would work:

```
private Integer getnumber(){
  Integer i = null;
  try {
    i = new Integer(5);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    i = new Integer(0);
  }
  finally{
    i = new Integer(7);
  }
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigned the value in `finally` and before that you returned in `try`

The code in finally always executes,but you are already returned the value in `try`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the return statement executes before the `finally` executes, and the value of `i` is 5 when the return statement executes.
To verify this, you can do this

```
private Integer getnumber(){
Integer i = null;
try{
   i = new Integer(5);
   return i;
}catch(Exception e){return 0;}
finally{
  i = new Integer(7);
  System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

This prints `7`, because the `finally` block does execute, but simply after the `return` statement.

Comment: This is wrong, finally will be called even if there is a return in try.

Comment: What I mean is the value of i is returned and then finally block is executed

Comment: You can check that value printed is 7 that is from finally block but the actual returned value is 5

Comment: @JunedAhsan The answer is correct. It was just worded confusingly.

Comment: @Prasad Kharkar, you are still wrong saying "value of i is returned and then finally block is executed " . finally will be executed after the return statement, but return will not be be pushed out of stack until finally finishes.

Comment: @JLRishe No answer is not correct as it says "This is because the return takes place before the finally executes". This statement is wrong.

Comment: wrong answer, you didn't understand the logic

Comment: @JunedAhsan I think you're just needlessly nitpicking semantics. The return statement executes before the `finally` block, and the return value is determined when the return statment executes. This is why changing `i` has no effect on the returned value.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Please let me know the full explanation for the same. It will help me understand the concept thoroughly

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Read a similar post, there is a proof code to determine that finally is called no matter whether there is a return or not in try block. I was against only that part of your answer. Please don't take me wrong, just want your answer to be 100% correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java

Comment: @JunedAhsan Prasad never suggested that the `finally` does not execute. In fact, his example explicitly and intentionally demonstrates that the `finally` **does** execute.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I know that finally is called in any case. I've posted the same thing in my answer as it prints out 7. I could not convey that value is updated on the stack. Instead of update, I used return word for the value. I did not mean the control is returned

Comment: @JLRishe, THanks for understanding what I meant :)

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for very clear explanation in the edits

Answer (score 0):

In `finally` you are assigning the value but the value is returned before in `try` block

Answer (score 0):

Returned value is `5` because `return` is happening before `finally` block executes.